# Finding the id whose average sum is maximum compared to other id

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a MySQL table named "Rating" which contains (id, rateable_id, rating, user_id) columns. rateable_id is the id of a record which is rated and rated score is stored in rating (star rating). 
 
 All I want to do is to find particular rateable_id  (grouped by) whose sum average is maximum among other rateable_id.

In the above sample table , i should get rateable_id = 26 because its rating is max ((3+3)/2) = 3 as compared to other rateable_id.
raw sql or eloquent any preferred.

**Edit:** Sorry to mention but i have done roughly in not standard way 
 Anyway it returns the answer but i am looking using nested select answer. averageRating is willvincent package for counting avg sum of rating. $popular_post returns the id whose average rating sum maximum.

```
$posts =  "App\Opportunity"::all(); //where(createdate < 1month)        
        $i=11;
        $cr=0;
        $pr=0;
        $mi = 0; //max index    
        $maxR=0; //max rating value 
        for($i=0; $i< count($posts); $i++)  
        {
            $cr = $posts[$i]->averageRating; //current rating   
            if($cr)<br> 
            {
                if($cr > $maxR) 
                {
                    $maxR = $cr;    
                    $mi = $i;   

                }               
            }
            else
            {
           //     echo "skip<br>";
            }                                   
        }

        $popular_post = ($posts[$mi]->id);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve this problem?

Comment: Read at these links about Grouping and Averaging. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_avg.asp - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I have edited the post which i have tried but not in standard way. It's working fine but unreliable.

Comment: And for next time, no pictures thanks. Instead, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need 2 selects:

```
SELECT MAX(rating) rating, rateable_id FROM (
    SELECT AVG(rating) rating, rateable_id FROM table GROUP BY reateble_id
) GROUP BY rateable_id ORDER BY rating LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This is definitely on the right path.  +1 for suggesting query logic over php loops. Time == $$

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you little bit.

```
$ratings = Rating::all()->groupBy('rateable_id');

$topList = [];

foreach($ratings as $key => $value){
    $topList[$key] = ($value->sum('rating')) / count($value);
}

arsort($topList);                          //sort the array by top values
$max_rateable_id = key($topList);          //key of first item of the array
$max_rating = reset($topList);             //value of first item of the array
$both = [$max_rateable_id => $max_rating]; //key and value of the first item of the array
```